# Custom Design Google script CardService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Script development, and trying to develop Gmail Add-On, somehow I achieve some basic stuff like read gmail message and install add-on to gmail.

Now I am looking to design my Gmail Add-On, like in row and multiple column or changes in default behavior of any elements. As it use CardService I am unable to write any style on it.

So how can I design or apply any style to CardService components.

Comment: Did you solved it somehow ?

Comment: @shark please refer to answer, there is no other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as you've already mentioned, due to cross-platform compatibility for Gmail addons, the CardService [doesn't allow you to use client-side scripting](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/restrictions#use_client-side_scripting) such as CSS or JavaScript.

[There is some basic formatting which you're able to do in a card](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting), but it's limited to text and the number of methods available is limited.